# Prove that $||v + w||^2 = ||v||^2 + ||w||^2$ if and only if $v$, and $w$ are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

> Let $v$ and $w$ be elements of an inner product space. Prove that
> $||v + w||^2 = ||v||^2 + ||w||^2$ if and only if $v$, and $w$ are orthogonal.

I'll answer my own question below

Comment: Since there's no way of getting privileges other than reputation, I've resorted to answering my own questions especially since most of my answers are unaccepted. I'd like an explanation for any downvotes please, and tell me what I should do instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: "i.p." is to mean inner-product, and have others have noted, I’m assuming we’re only dealing with $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
||v+w||^2 &= \langle v+w,v+w\rangle\\
&= \langle v,v\rangle +\langle v,w\rangle +\langle w,v\rangle +\langle w,w\rangle \\
&= \langle v,v\rangle +2\langle v,w\rangle+\langle w,w\rangle &&(\text{since } \langle v,w\rangle=\langle w,v\rangle \text{ when i.p. exists})
\end{aligned}
$$

And

$$
||v||^2+||w||^2=\langle v,v\rangle +\langle w,w\rangle
$$

Now

$$
||v + w||^2 = ||v||^2 + ||w||^2\\
\implies\langle v,v\rangle +\color{red}{2\langle v,w\rangle } +\langle w,w\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle +\langle w,w\rangle
$$

This is only true **iff** $2\langle v,w \rangle=0\implies \langle v,w \rangle=0$ which is the definition of $2$ vectors being orthogonal.

Comment: If  $\left< u,w \right> =ib$ with $b\ne 0$,then  $\left< u,w \right> +\left< w,u \right> =ib-ib=0$. But $u$  and $w$ are not orthogonal.

Comment: @fusheng Is my proof simply incomplete or is the original statement false?

Comment: @fusheng and I thought that if $\langle u,w \rangle$ was a defined inner product, that $\langle u,w \rangle = \langle w,u \rangle$?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$, it's instead $\langle u,w \rangle = \overline{\langle w,u \rangle}$.

Comment: Your proof is true for an inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$. Bur if it is over  $\mathbb{C}$, it is not true.

Comment: @fusheng ohhh ok. I’m assuming we’re dealing with $\mathbb{R}$ because that’s all we’ve done so far in Linear Algebra, and the question is to prove the statement true.